# Spring-WS Decrypt body part

Tags: spring, soap-client, spring-ws

so I'm communicating with a service via soap. The repose body looks as follows.

```
<xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
        <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier">plU1gwH/05daoxwRJYvuAViKUp4=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </dsig:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <xenc:CipherValue>J/AQ6BnIAbTgrXYkRAg7mB1sKEQcroAvc/5Gy1a60oN+nxISGjS+W/sdbX9XAG8paAb+Zb6WoOyxw+9ZN9SFpq3TpDnjO/F/6DDisVOG5i65KnC3bDG1Y2tpRsGZzKvzPGB3O2mmnBGSfVb5FNDZoeBLQqlHf8iKc8GPQlTuAOWhEKStU20RXN9FjmSumiYxa0EUitFoGicVHg2ym5EEuVb10yGbkMPGcqGb2hZc/4pAJC8RORZmyXV2cZFin7ngfneD6uz7y5i3RPVvBNtN4kET75AoLJd3vJUXOevSXojiSoYb89adjRtrs2lVtthX+yh7x1ddwSeJ7+Ah5kW6JA==</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:ReferenceList>
          <xenc:DataReference URI="#G0x7f16e7565138-46D"/>
        </xenc:ReferenceList>
      </xenc:EncryptedKey> 
...
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Body-ab9464bb-3e1e-4d4f-94a6-9f75b7e4f6bd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <c:validateResponse xmlns:a="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:b="http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:c="http://hcv.health.ontario.ca/">
      <xenc:EncryptedData Id="G0x7f16e7565138-46D" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
        <xenc:CipherData>
          <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
      </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </c:validateResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

note that validateResponse has encrypted data. This was encrypted using the public key from the request. When I try an do webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive, I get the JAXBElement is always null.

Below is my security interceptor

```
@Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun wss4jSecurityInterceptor(): Wss4jSecurityInterceptor {
        val securityInterceptor = Wss4jSecurityInterceptor()


        // set security actions: Timestamp Signature SAMLTokenSigned SAMLTokenUnsigned
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp Signature UsernameToken")
        //securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(securityCallbackHandler())
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("USERNAME")
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("PASSWORD")
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType(WSConstants.PW_TEXT)

        // sign the request
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(signingCertName)
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(signingCertPassword)
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementTimeToLive(5000)
        securityInterceptor.setTimestampStrict(false)
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(myCrypto())
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts(
                "{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;" +
                "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;" +
                "{Element}{http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/}EBS;" +
                "{Element}{http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/}IDP;"
        )
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureDigestAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1")
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1")
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference")
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementMustUnderstand(true)

        val keyStoreCallbackHandler = KeyStoreCallbackHandler()
        keyStoreCallbackHandler.setPrivateKeyPassword("PASSWORD")
        securityInterceptor.setValidationDecryptionCrypto(myCrypto())
        securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(keyStoreCallbackHandler)
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionParts("{Element}{http://hcv.health.ontario.ca/}validateResponse;")
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionCrypto(myCrypto())
        securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("Encrypt")
        securityInterceptor.setValidationActor("USERNAME")
        securityInterceptor.setValidateRequest(false)
        securityInterceptor.setValidateResponse(false)

        securityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet()
        return securityInterceptor
    }
```

EDIT: Updated the soap request with part of the header

Reading the specs for the server I'm coummunicating with,

If any response data is specified to be enc
rypted, by the specific web service technical 
specification, the data will be encrypted using, at least, the AES128-
CBC symmetric 
encryption algorithm with the public key belonging to the signer of the initial SOAP 
request. The encryption algorithm may be increased based on the specific web service 
technical specification.

I'm not sure how to be able to do that

Comment: Don't call `afterPropertiesSet` in your code (although that isn't related to your error). Did you actually inject that interceptor into the `WebServiceTemplate` that you are using?

Comment: Yes, I know it's working because the request has the correct signatures. I didnt include it because my post would be more code than SO would let me post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out.

It was skipping the validation

```
securityInterceptor.setValidateRequest(false)
securityInterceptor.setValidateResponse(false)
```

needed to be removed

Comment: Is there any way to log the raw data on the encrypt field?